# Ozeki SDK - Axis camera RTSP authentication failure

Tags: c#, .net, h.264, rtsp, ozeki

I'm using Ozeki SDK with C# for streaming RTSP from AXIS P1204 camera.
When I try to connect to the camera, nothing happens and no video is streamed.

Here is the code i'm using to stream video:

```
Camera = IPCameraFactory.GetCamera("rtsp://192.168.0.90:554/axis-media/media.amp", "root", "pass");
Connector.Connect(Camera.VideoChannel, ImageProvider);
Camera.Start();
VideoViewer.Start();
```

I traced the network traffic with wireshark:

[image]
As it seems, the Ozeki SDK can't login to the Axis P1204. With VLC media player, I can get the video stream with no problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The snippet is quite short but you get a 401 Unauthorized response. Initially, you could try to get access to the camera by enabling anonymous access In Basic Setup  Users). Depending on Ozeki SDK having support for basic and/or digest authentication, you can configure the camera to allow password type Unencrypted (basic authentication) or Encrypted (digest authentication).

Answer (score 0):

maybe take a look if your camera is ONVIF compatible, you can see it on the onvif device manager :) 
If it is, you should take the rtsp from there...and if your camera has an username and a password you should add this as well. I tried a lot, but it never connected me with AXIS, so I guess its a fault from them, or from the streaming thats different.

Comment: This should be in the comment section and not answer